# ORA-06530: "Reference to uninitialized composite" even if initialized

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have read solutions for solving the error but I don't know why still I get error,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tmp_object IS OBJECT (
            id      NUMBER,
            code    NUMBER
            );
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tmp_table IS TABLE OF tmp_object;
```

and the anonymous block to use them:

```
DECLARE
    cnt         PLS_INTEGER;
    tmp_tbl     tmp_table := tmp_table();
BEGIN
    SELECT regexp_count('34, 87, 908, 123, 645', '[^,]+', 1) str
    INTO cnt
    FROM dual;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Counter is: ' || cnt);

    FOR i IN 1..cnt
    LOOP
        tmp_tbl.EXTEND;
        SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR('34, 87, 908, 123, 645', '[^,]+', 1,i)) str
        INTO tmp_tbl(tmp_tbl.LAST).code
        FROM dual;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tmp_tbl(i).code);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I use Oracle Database 12c and below is the error in SQL Developer 4.2:

> Error report -
>
> ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite
>
> ORA-06512: at line 14
>
> 6530. 00000 -  "Reference to uninitialized composite"
>
> *Cause:    An object, LOB, or other composite was referenced as a
>              left hand side without having been initialized.
>
> *Action:   Initialize the composite with an appropriate constructor
>              or whole-object assignment.

Comment: you dont have the LAST datatag in that time, that's why is uninitialized

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax that you are using works for RECORDs

```
SQL> set serverout on;
SQL> 
SQL> DECLARE
  2      cnt         PLS_INTEGER;
  3      l_code      NUMBER;
  4      TYPE tmp_object IS RECORD (
  5              id      NUMBER,
  6              code    NUMBER
  7              );
  8      TYPE tmp_table IS TABLE OF tmp_object;
  9      tmp_tbl     tmp_table := tmp_table();
 10  BEGIN
 11      SELECT regexp_count('34, 87, 908, 123, 645', '[^,]+', 1) str
 12      INTO cnt
 13      FROM dual;
 14  
 15      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Counter is: ' || cnt);
 16  
 17      FOR i IN 1..cnt
 18      LOOP
 19          tmp_tbl.EXTEND;
 20  
 21          SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR('34, 87, 908, 123, 645', '[^,]+', 1,i)) str
 22          INTO tmp_tbl(tmp_tbl.LAST).code
 23          FROM dual;
 24          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tmp_tbl(i).code);
 25  
 26      END LOOP;
 27  END;
 28  /

Counter is: 5
34
87
908
123
645

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

To use OBJECT, you have to use object constructor to insert into the table of that object

```
SQL> 
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tmp_object IS OBJECT (
  2              id      NUMBER,
  3              code    NUMBER
  4              );
  5  
  6  /

Type created

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tmp_table IS TABLE OF tmp_object;
  2  /

Type created

SQL> 
SQL> DECLARE
  2      cnt         PLS_INTEGER;
  3      tmp_tbl     tmp_table := tmp_table();
  4  BEGIN
  5      SELECT regexp_count('34, 87, 908, 123, 645', '[^,]+', 1) str
  6      INTO cnt
  7      FROM dual;
  8  
  9      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Counter is: ' || cnt);
 10  
 11      FOR i IN 1..cnt
 12      LOOP
 13          tmp_tbl.EXTEND;
 14  
 15          SELECT tmp_object(i, TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR('34, 87, 908, 123, 645', '[^,]+', 1,i)))
 16          INTO tmp_tbl(tmp_tbl.last)
 17          FROM dual;
 18  
 19          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tmp_tbl(i).code);
 20      END LOOP;
 21  END;
 22  /

Counter is: 5
34
87
908
123
645

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

**UPDATE: To open a cursor on the collection**

> You have to use a ref cursor to collect the value from the collection
>   using TABLE function and CAST function to help oracle identify the
>   datatype of the collection.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2      cnt      PLS_INTEGER;
  3      tmp_tbl  tmp_table := tmp_table();
  4      c_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  5      l_id     NUMBER;
  6      l_code   NUMBER;
  7  BEGIN
  8      SELECT regexp_count('34, 87, 908, 123, 645', '[^,]+', 1) str INTO cnt FROM dual;
  9  
 10      dbms_output.put_line('Counter is: ' || cnt);
 11  
 12      FOR i IN 1 .. cnt LOOP
 13          tmp_tbl.extend;
 14  
 15          SELECT tmp_object(i, TRIM(regexp_substr('34, 87, 908, 123, 645', '[^,]+', 1, i)))
 16            INTO tmp_tbl(tmp_tbl.last)
 17            FROM dual;
 18  
 19      END LOOP;
 20  
 21      OPEN c_cursor FOR
 22          SELECT * FROM TABLE(CAST(tmp_tbl AS tmp_table));
 23      LOOP
 24          FETCH c_cursor
 25              INTO l_id,
 26                   l_code;
 27          EXIT WHEN c_cursor%NOTFOUND;
 28          dbms_output.put_line(l_id || ',' || l_code);
 29      END LOOP;
 30      CLOSE c_cursor;
 31  
 32  END;
 33  /

Counter is: 5
1,34
2,87
3,908
4,123
5,645

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Comment: now if I want to select from `tmp_tbl` table how can I do that? (fetch it to a cursor)

Comment: how can I do DML operations on these collection type tables?

Comment: You cannot run DML directly on collection types. You have to find the subscript of the record that you want to update and then update it using the same subscript. e.g - `tmp_tbl(i).code := 99;` where `i` is the subscript of the record that needs to be updated.

Comment: does [this link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/complex-recordsets#PLSQLTables) do kind of DML on collection type tables? or it is something else?

Comment: to replay to your last comment, can I update the subscript this way: `tmp_tbl(i).code := tmp_tbl(i).code + 18;` , or I have to do like the _oracle-base_ link I mentioned?

Comment: The link is doing nothing extra from what you are doing, I cannot see any UPDATE happening in the example given over there. And for `tmp_tbl(i).code := tmp_tbl(i).code + 18;`, I would say YES.

Comment: what is the best practice of using Oracle OBJECTs & RECORDs, I mean which one is better for performance or anything I don't know...?

Comment: OBJECTs and RECORDs more or less have the same purpose, but the OBJECTs are at database level which is once created can be used in many procedures where as RECORDs have scope within the procedure where they are created. You can open a cursor on OBJECTS but not on RECORDS. You can also check [Global Temporary Tables](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables) which works just like any ordinary table but DML operations are faster than normal table and their scope is limited to the current session.